# Link 2 different excel files

Tags: hyperlink

I got an Excel file name File A with 8 different worksheets. How do I link all data from File A to a brand new File B? Any changes to File A will automatically update File B. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy as you are only requiring updates in File B from File A, rather than in both directions. Since a complete clone would probably be easiest with just a Save (of File A as File B) I am assuming you only require this for a limited number of cells. Copy a cell from File A into the desired location in File B and paste the Clipboard content with Paste Special <kbd>Paste Link</kbd>.

The values however may be out of synchronisation unless both files are open at the same time in the same Excel instance.